# ANGULAR Cannot find control with path: 'childrenFormArray -> [object Object] -> gender'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on an angular project and I am trying to add multiple children with their age and gender dynamically with reactive forms . Though the form is being added , the delete part of it is not working. Everytime I try to add , an error keeps popping up

```
Cannot find control with name: 'childrenFormArray'
```

This is my ts code

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.childrenFormGroup= this.formBuilder.group({
     childrenFormArray: this.formBuilder.array([ this.createItem() ])
   });
 }

 createItem(): FormGroup {
   return this.formBuilder.group({
     gender: new FormControl(''),
     age:  new FormControl(''),
  
   });
 }

 addItem(): void {

   if(this.childrenFormGroup.get('childrenFormArray'['controls'].length<this.numberOfChildren) {
       this.childrenFormArray = this.childrenFormGroup.get('childrenFormArray') as FormArray;
       this.childrenFormArray.push(this.createItem()); 
       this.addItem();
   }
   else if(this.childrenFormGroup.get('childrenFormArray'['controls']>this.numberOfChildren) {
     this.childrenFormArray = this.childrenFormGroup.get('childrenFormArray') as FormArray;
     this.childrenFormArray.removeAt(this.childrenFormArray.length-1);
     this.addItem()
 }
```

}

This my html code to print the form

```html
  <div class="col-12 ">
     <fieldset class="form-group ">
       <label class="form-label " for="numberOfChildren">Number Of Children</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control " id="numberOfChildren"   [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Enter number of children" (input)="addItem()" [(ngModel)]="numberOfChildren" required>
          <div formArrayName="childrenFormArray" *ngFor="let item of childrenFormGroup.get('childrenFormArray')['controls']; let i = index;">
             <div [formGroupName]="childrenFormGroup.get('childrenFormArray')['controls'][i]">
                <select formControlName="gender" >
                   <option value="male">Male</option>
                   <option value="female">Female</option>
                   <option value="other">Others</option>
                </select>
                 <input type="number" formControlName="age" placeholder="Age of Child">
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your html matches your form e.g your form has the structure

```
  childrenFormGroup: FormGroup
    childrenFormArray : FormArray
      [0] : FormGroup
          gender: FormControl
          age: FormControl
      [1] : FormGroup
          gender: FormControl
          age: FormControl
```

Now we can go back to your form and try to meet above

```html
<form [formGroup]='childrenFormGroup'>
    <div class="col-12 ">
     <fieldset class="form-group ">
       <label class="form-label " for="numberOfChildren">Number Of Children</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control " id="numberOfChildren"   [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Enter number of children" (input)="addItem()" [(ngModel)]="numberOfChildren" required>
          <ng-container formArrayName="childrenFormArray">
            <div *ngFor="let item of childrenFormGroup.get('childrenFormArray')['controls']; let i = index;" [formGroupName]='i'>
             <div>
                <select formControlName="gender" >
                   <option value="male">Male</option>
                   <option value="female">Female</option>
                   <option value="other">Others</option>
                </select>
                 <input type="number" formControlName="age" placeholder="Age of Child">
      </div>
```

Note this two lines

```
<ng-container formArrayName="childrenFormArray">
...
 [formGroupName]='i'
```